# C# DateTime.TryParseExact when reading string of date from Excel

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a list of string from excel and parse it to a date.

I specified the format of the string in excel was `d/M/yyyy` but sometimes I got the string in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`, `d/MM/yyyy`, `d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss`, `dd/M/yyyy h:m:ss`, ........ etc.

I don't care what the time is and I only want to get the string of date and parse it to a date. Do I need to define a huge array to contain all the combination of format of date and time before calling `TryParseExact`? or is there any smart way to do so?

Comment: So Excel does not recognize it as a date?

Comment: If you do not know the exact format, use `TryParse` instead of `TryParseExact`...

Comment: For example: "8/07/2012" TryParse parse the date to 7th Aug 2012, not the date 8th Jul 2012

Comment: Use the tryparse overload that accepts a culture then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is going to be to ensure that the data from excel is in the format you want, but you can split up the date string, and make a Date object from the resulting arrays:

```
var datePart = (excelString.Split(' '))[0];
var dateParts = datePart.Split('/');
DateTime finalDate = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(dateParts[2]), Int32.Parse(dateParts[1]), Int32.Parse(dateParts[0]));
```

While this will work, since it is hard-coded, it will break if the format of `dd/mm/yyyy` ever changes to say `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 2):

You could Regex to rearrange the date string to M/d/y which can be parsed easily:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)(.*)", @"$2/$1/$3"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```